# mySQL Transaction in Java: Using results from queries in a transaction?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, transactions

To being the transaction I do:

```
con.setAutoCommit(false);
```

To end the transaction I do:

```
con.commit();
```

In my transaction I have an sql statment and I need to iterate over that results to generate the next set of statements.

Can I use the results of the queries within a transaction?

Comment: It is. I wanted to be 100% sure. Thanks